# How to replace a repeating char at only a particular place in String?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like : Hi/I/Jack/there

which contains multiple '/' between values. And these values are not of fixed length(can be any length)

And I need to replace only second occurrence of '/' with another string that means the Output should be.. 
Hi/IamJack/there

How should I achieve this? tried with String.replace and some logic but it's replacing all occurrences where as I need only 2nd occurrence to replace. And I'm restricted to use String only(not StringBuilder or something else)

Comment: Depends on exact requirements. Is it "replace part between first and second /" or what? That woukd be easy with regexp, but if requirement is more complex/dynamic, you could split by / and then join again after replacing the parts you want.

Comment: `str.replaceFirst("^([^/]*/)([^/]*)", "$1$2am")`

Comment: @hyde- I want 2nd '/' to be replaced with 'am'.

Comment: @AvinashRaj- what is it actually? and it's throwing exception "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2"

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. It's much easier to answer if you format your question so there is description, example input, expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count `/` by each element in String

```
    String s = "Hi/I/Jack/there";

    for(int i=0,count=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='/')// if the i'th element is '/'
        {
            count++;
            if(count==2)//it's second '/'
            {
                //separate to two part by second '/' and add what you want at middle
                s = s.substring(0,i) + "am" +s.substring(i+1,s.length());                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: output s = `Hi/Iam/Jack/there` at end. can't figure out your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help..It's working :) but I edited the question..can you edit your answer for the output 'Hi/IamJack/there'

Comment: @TomN-- Thanks a lot for solving my problem.I searched whole site but din't find this type question and I was wasting time. I just created my account , is it why I'm unable to upvote your answer?

Comment: @ashG updated. subString() is control by index of String. you can change `i` for test. and notice that you can use `StringBuilder` to build and re-build String more effective.

Comment: @ashG you don't have much reputation to vote(15↑),  it's fine. :)

Comment: @ashG or you can accept the answer. Both we'll receive some reputations .

Answer (score 3):

**The idea:**

- find the index `n` of the second '/' with **int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)**
- use that index to take two separate substrings of your string, so

  `s.substring(0, n)` would be `"Hi/I"` and

  `s.substring(n + 1)` would be `"Jack/there"`
- add `"am/"` between `"Hi/I"` and `"Jack/there"` by concatenating them:

  `"Hi/I" + "am/" + "Jack/there"`

---

**Code:**

```
String s = "Hi/I/Jack/there";
int n = s.indexOf("/", s.indexOf("/") + 1); // index of the second '/'

String firstString = s.substring(0, n); // "Hi/I"
String lastString = s.substring(n + 1); // "Jack/there"`
String result = firstString + "am/" + lastString;

System.out.println(result);
// outputs Hi/Iam/Jack/there
```

Comment: You seem to assume that the second slash is always at the 3rd position...

Comment: This won't help me cause there's no fixed length for values..sometimes it may be Hiiiii..like that

Answer (score 1):

You can split and join the string

```
String var ="Hi/I/Jack/there";
String [] arr = var.split("/");
```

and join with the new string you want

Answer (score 1):

```
public class  S {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hi/I/Jack/there";
            int index = s.indexOf("/", s.indexOf("/")+1); // find index of "/" starting after first "/"
            String result = s.substring(0, index) + "am" + s.substring(index+1);
            System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somethin like this with lookaround regex.

```
String[] tokens = "Hi/I/Jack/there".split("((?<=/)|(?=/))"); // split string to array [Hi, /, I, Am, Jack, /, there]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
tokens[3] = "Am"; // second "/" will be always on 4th place, replace it with "Am"
System.out.println(String.join("", tokens)); // join again
```